# Trigger php script through code

Tags: php, android, triggers

I want my app to trigger a php script. Basically, all it needs to do is visit an url with some get variables (something like www.example.com/foo.php?id=1). Preferably without opening any browser.

Comment: You could get the answer from Google in less time

Answer (score 2):

Here is a resource from the Android SDK website that demonstrates the HttpUrlConnection object in action:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

This call would be made programmatically, without showing anything to the user.